# div overlaying image at large screen size not stacking as screen shrinks

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Apologies for the poor title, my terminology is weak but I am working on it.

I have a div partially covering a background image when the screen width is at a larger size. For smaller screen widths, I would like that div to drop below the background image rather than continue to overlay the background image—as what currently I have here in this pen:

https://codepen.io/Ywehc/pen/KQqQeN

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="width:cover">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490641525855-f5ffa411459d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=85bad8135a13687bbd2ac661023e8dc4&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1189&q=80" style="width:100%">
  <div class="overlaid-div" style="background-color: blue; height: 15em; width: 20em; margin-left:50%; margin-top: -100px; position: relative">
  </div>
  <div class="randomelement" style="width: 30em; height:10em; background-color: black">
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically I would like to keep overlay for large screen widths, but as screen width went smaller, the divs should stack vertically and the blue div should not overlay anymore.

Thank you kindly!

Comment: did you mean to hide the blue div when screen smaller or make the blue div below the image when screen smaller>

Comment: Below the image (between the two other divs) when smaller.

Comment: Of course, it won't stack. That's because you aren't using any of the responsive Bootstrap features at all. Why is this even tagged with `bootstrap-4`? You don't need Bootstrap if you aren't using any of its features.

Comment: I had thought the container-fluid was a bootstrap feature, my mistake. I tagged it bootstrap 4 because I felt the solution would involve bootstrap features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a single media query to achieve this (adjust break-point width as necessary).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .overlaid-div {
    /* !important is needed to override your inline margin style */
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  } 
}
```

https://codepen.io/antibland/pen/XZgEzo

Answer (score 1):

add this to css.
You should use `@media` to change the margin based on desired screen size

```
@media only screen and (min-width:400px){ // Change 400px to your desired the maximum of smallest width screen
  .overlaid-div {
    margin-top: 0%
  }
}  
@media only screen and (min-width:1000px){
  .overlaid-div {
    margin-top: -10%
  }
}
```

and, delete `margin-top` from inner style